# Jquery pushing variables into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 pieces of seperate code and need to combine them to work together, the one is 3 sliders where you select different values and get a price depending on the selected values. The other code needs to add these values into an array. At the moment the ram, diskspace and cpu values are filled in hardcoded but I need it to grab the values of the sliders and use it. The slider values get saved to there own values, but I don't know how to make them work together. This is what I have at the moment for the shopping cart where the values get inserted into:

```
$(".add-to-cart").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevents the links from doing their default behaviour
    var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
    var price =  Number($(this).attr("data-price")); //so this needs to be the totalPrice from the sliders fiddle
    var ram = Number($(this).attr("data-ram"));// this needs to be the ram from the sliders fiddle
    var diskSpace =Number($(this).attr("data-diskSpace"));// this needs to be the diskSpace from the sliders fiddle
    var cpu = Number($(this).attr("data-cpu"));// this needs to be the cpu from the sliders fiddle
    addItemToCart(name,price,1,ram,diskSpace,cpu);
    displayCart();
});



var cart = [];
var Item = function (name,price,quantity,ram,diskSpace,cpu){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.ram = ram;
    this.diskSpace = diskSpace;
    this.cpu = cpu;
};

//addItemToCart(name,price,quantity)

function addItemToCart(name,price,quantity,ram,diskSpace,cpu){
for (var i in cart){
    if(cart[i].name === name){
        cart[i].quantity +=quantity;
        saveCart();
        return;
    }

}
    var item = new Item(name,price,quantity,ram,diskSpace,cpu);
    cart.push(item);

}
```

And the slider function:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="slider" id="ram" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="10" data-slider-step="1" />
      <hr />

  <input class="slider" id="diskSpace" data-slider-id='ex1Slider2' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="10" />
       <hr />
      <input  class="slider" id="cpu" data-slider-id='ex1Slider3' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="4" data-slider-step="1" />

       <hr />



  </div>
  Prijs:
<div id = "prijs">
</div>


 var minSliderValue = $("#ram").data("slider-min");
var maxSliderValue = $("#ram").data("slider-max");

$('#ram').slider({
    value : 0,
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'RAM: ' + value + 'GB';
    }
});

$('#diskSpace').slider({
    value : 0,
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Disk Space: ' + value + 'GB';
    }
});

$('#cpu').slider({
    value : 0,
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'CPU : ' + value + ' Cores';
    }
});

// If You want to change input text using slider handler
$('.slider').on('slide', function(slider){

  var ram = $("#ram").val();
  var diskSpace = $("#diskSpace").val();
  var cpu = $("#cpu").val();
var totalPrice=(parseFloat(ram)*3.5 + parseFloat(diskSpace)*0.15+ parseFloat(cpu)*6.5).toFixed(2);
  $("#prijs").html(totalPrice);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4c2m3cup/42/

Answer (score 0):

If those 2 codes are in the same file you can easily get the values with:

```
$("#ram").val();
$("#cpu").val();
```

if the above code is included in the same page as the html included, the code i mentioned will work as well.